# What are the "Houses of Lamentation"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In *The Lord of the Rings*, the Witch King says

> "Come not between the Nazgûl and his prey! Or he will not slay thee in
> thy turn. He will bear thee away to the Houses of Lamentation, beyond
> all darkness, where thy flesh shall be devoured, and thy shrivelled
> mind be left naked to the Lidless Eye."

What are these Houses? Are they a metaphor or a real place? It seems like a real threat, not an idle one. He is a sorceror after all so presumably it's something he could really do.

Comment: FWIW, the original draft of this passage shown in HoMe has this dialogue almost identical, just without the capitalization: "*'Come not between the Nazgûl and his prey,' said a cold voice, 'or he will bear thee away to the houses of lamentation, beyond all darkness where thy flesh shall be devoured and thy shrivelled mind be left naked.'*"

Comment: They appear as a [literal place](https://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/B%C3%A2r_N%C3%ADrnaeth,_the_Houses_of_Lamentation#:~:text=It%20was%20at%20B%C3%A2r%20N%C3%ADrnaeth,of%20their%20buildings%20and%20courtyards.) in Lord of the Rings Online and [LOTR: The Card Game](https://www.categoryonegames.com/catalog/lord_of_the_rings_tcg-mount_doom/houses_of_lamentation/52014)

Comment: Houses of Lamentation are dungeons in Mordor.

Comment: I read it as a metaphor for "somewhere deep in Barad-Dur".  I don't think Sauron kept "out-houses" (unless you count _Sammath Naur_), but I could be wrong ;)

Comment: @ibid I have just checked in a Seventh impression from 1973, and it does _not_ contain the capitalization, so that is a posthumous edit!

Comment: @m4r35n357: Not necessarily. It may have been changed, then accidentally reverted, then changed back. Tolkien had some complaints about just that happening on several occasions.

Comment: @Shamshiel well if that is so I am struggling to care ;)

Comment: @m4r35n357 - I've just checked and it is not capitalized in the current text either. Perhaps OP added the capitalization.

Comment: @ibid why didn't I think of that? ;)

Comment: I don't _think_ this phrase is used anywhere else, so we have very little to go on, but I'd say it probably means Barad Dur. It is notable that the Mouth of Sauron threatens that Frodo will be taken there if Gandalf and Aragorn don't surrender (The Black Gate Opens), so this seems to be a standard threat for mortals who make a nuisance of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The Lidless Eye refers to the eye Frodo and Sam see when they climb Mount Doom:

> Far off the shadows of Sauron hung; but torn by some gust of wind out
> of the world, or else moved by some great disquiet within, the
> mantling clouds swirled, and for a moment drew aside; and then he saw,
> rising black, blacker and darker than the vast shades amid which it
> stood, the cruel pinnacles and iron crown of the topmost tower of
> Barad-dûr. One moment only it stared out, but as from some great
> window immeasurably high there stabbed northward a flame of red, the
> flicker of a piercing Eye; and then the shadows were furled again and
> the terrible vision was removed.

That you are "left naked to the Lidless Eye" in the Houses of Lamentation suggests they are a dungeon in Barad Dur.  The tone suggests a waiting place before or after death, a sort of purgatory.  There are multiple places like this, like the [Halls of Mandos](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Halls_of_Mandos), where Elves wait until they reincarnate.  Tolkien Gateway also mentions the last words of Thorin:

> 'Farewell, good thief,' he said. 'I go now to the halls of waiting to
> sit beside my fathers, until the world is renewed.'

The Witch King is invoking images of eternal dread to frighten his listeners.

Comment: This looks like it could be a good answer, but as written it seems a bit confusing. I think you need to be clearer that the HofL are *not* Mandos or anything related to Mandos or the halls of waiting Thorin speaks of.  In particular, I see no evidence that the HofL are a post-death thing -- quite the contrary!

Comment: Indeed, it could be a sort of "half life" like the ghosts of Dunharrow?

Comment: "The Witch King is invoking images of eternal dread to frighten his listeners." Unfortunately for him, he was addressing somebody who was as unafraid of death as anybody ever gets.